# How to remove a value from array in quasar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have object array in quasar

```
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 12: {…}, 13: {…}, 14: {…}, 15: {…}}
1
: 
{id: 1, title: 'Supreme Court dubs Manipur', news: 'PTI, New Delhi, JUL 20 2023, 11:23 ISTUPDATED: JUL…isturbing-asks-centre-to-take-action-1238849.html', created_by: 10000001, updated_by: null, …}
2
: 
{id: 2, title: 'test for reverse', news: 'reverse test In the above program, the user is pro…d to enter a string. That string is passed to the', created_by: 10000001, updated_by: 10000001, …}
12
: 
{id: 12, title: 'cc', news: 'cc', created_by: 10000001, updated_by: null, …}
13
: 
{id: 13, title: 'aa', news: 'aa', created_by: 10000001, updated_by: null, …}
14
: 
{id: 14, title: 'jj', news: 'jj', created_by: 10000001, updated_by: null, …}
15
: 
{id: 15, title: 'mm', news: 'h', created_by: 10000001, updated_by: null, …}
[[Prototype]]
:
```

How to remove to complete row with key 12?

I have tried

```
let id = 12
master.news.splice(id, 1)
```

But getting error: **Uncaught TypeError: master.news.splice is not a function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `master.news` looks like an object with indexes as keys, you could use the `delete` operator to remove that property :

```js
let id = 12
delete master.news[id]
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method works on an array but as per the data structure, `master.news` is an object with numbered keys (e.g., 1, 2, 12, etc.). Hence, you can not perform splice directly on it.

To make it work you have to use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator.

You can try this **:**

```
let id = 12
if (master.news[id]) {
  delete master.news[id]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter method for remove object from array

```
arrayName.filter(item => {item.id !== 12})
```

if your data in object you can use delete operator like this:

```
delete objectName[12]
```